# Avoiding resuming app at lock screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity

I have a game which uses OpenGL ES for rendering. And it requires that I reload all the textures on resuming the app. When I press the homekey and exit (pause the app) and then resume it, it works fine. But when I use the power key to turn off the screen then turn on the screen, the app resumes at the lock screen itself (Slide to unlock screen). Is there anyway I can avoid this? Because the resume is not proper, if I unlock the screen after a slight delay (10 secs) the game will reload again and all I end up seeing is a white-screen. I want to mainly, if I can stop the app from resuming at the lock screen. I want the app to resume after the screen has been unlocked.

Thanks
Akash

Comment: You could cheat and have a "resume" dialogue that appears when onResume() is called. The user has to press it to unpause the game. This might work better anyway, especially if unpausing before the user is ready is a problem

Comment: Like an alert pop-up? That wouldn't be ideal, but if I don't find any other solution, I'll have to take that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this in the activity.

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

it will show the application on top of the lock screen.

Comment: After 2 days of searching your answer worked for me . Awesome.

Comment: This did do the trick to a pint, but we found other activities that pop up (that are not set to avoid the lock) thusly pop up with the lock screen. So the lock screen when they appear and have to be dealt with to see the other activity that just came into being... so it doesn't fit every case, but definitely appears to have some utility.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the screen shange, then you can use, for avoid  restart:

android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize"