# Android application working with locked screen

Tags: android

For example I have an app that counts how many time Camera button was pressed. After locking the screen the app is not working, so is there any way to keep counting presses when screen is locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Apps and services are pause when the phone is locked, but you can acquire WAKE_LOCK key and do your task

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakeLock"); 
wakeLock.acquire();
```

this will hold the CPU open even if the screen off

Comment: if i understood correctly, i can set camera button as screen unlocker increment my value and then lock screen again?

Comment: This mean your  app run normally (counting button presses) screen lock doesn't problem to running the app anymore. if you want to  release the acquire lock can do using wakeLock.release(); whenever you want

Comment: I tried this method but its not helping. My app is not paused while screen is locked but i can't do any of input(  If u have any other ideas plz share. & Thnx 4 trying to help me

Comment: Can you more explain your task with code sample, then can provide good answer relevant to you

Comment: Task: App that can count real keyboard(camera, call, search any of them or all together doesn't matter) presses, even when the screen is locked (by power button). 

So far my app is working, but its not incrementing the value when screen is locked.

Comment: CODE:
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock"); 
wakeLock.acquire();}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
tv.setText(count+"");
count++;
return true;
}
return false;
}
}

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow is a method defined for activities, and won't require you to find a View first.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

I took that from [Avoiding resuming app at lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325395/avoiding-resuming-app-at-lock-screen?rq=1)