# How can I make my app work after lock screen?

Tags: android, locking, screen

I'm absolutely beginner in programing Android.
One of my first app is a torch.
It works pretty good but after the screen's locked LED lights for only few seconds.
Of course I want it works even after locking a phone.
Any help?

Comment: Take a look at this page http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/PreventSleepAndDim. The torch app that I have just prevents the phone from sleeping while it is on. Not exactly what you are after I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakeLock"); 
wakeLock.acquire();`

Extract from here: [Android application working with locked screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836950/android-application-working-with-locked-screen)