# Launch an Android app on the lock screen

Tags: android

I want to make an App that be launched on the lock screen, without inserting the lock code of the device. Is this posible?

I hope i have been clear.

Thank you for all.

Comment: have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836950/android-application-working-with-locked-screen

Answer (score 0):

Made this project a few days ago, hope this helps.

https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/Security-Lock-Android